# azure kubernetes service - self signed cert on private registry

Tags: azure, docker, ssl, kubernetes

I have a tunnel created between my azure subscription and my on-prem servers.  ON prem we have an artifactory server that is housing all of our docker images.  For all internal servers we have a company wide CA trust and all certs are generated from this.

However, when I try to deploy something to aks and reference this docker registry.  I am getting a cert error because the nodes themselves do not trust the "in house" self signed cert.

Is there anyway to get the root CA chain added to the nodes?  Or a way to tell the docker daemon on the aks nodes this is an insecure registry?

Answer (score 0):

Not one hundred percent sure, but you can try to use the docker config to create the secret for image pull, the command like this:

```
cat ~/.docker/config.json | base64
```

Then create the secret like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
 name: registrypullsecret
data:
 .dockerconfigjson: <base-64-encoded-json-here>
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Use this secret in your deployment or pod as the value of `imagePullSecrets`. For more details, see [Using a private Docker Registry with Kubernetes](https://blog.cloudhelix.io/using-a-private-docker-registry-with-kubernetes-f8d5f6b8f646).

Comment: I have done that in the past to add credentials.  But we aren't getting that far.  We are getting a cert error before even being able to authenticate.

Comment: @JasonB Do you try to use the command `kubectl create secret tls secret_name --key xxx.key -cert xxx.crt`?

Comment: @JasonB Any more updates? Do you solve the problem? If yes, please accept it.

Comment: this answer is not correct, this solves authentication on the registry but still does not solves the error with certificate validation.

Answer (score 0):

For the beginning I would recommend you to use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) to check connection between your azure cluster and on prem server.

Please use curl and curl -k and check if they both works(-k allow connections to SSL sites without certs, I assume it won't work, what means You don't have on prem certs on azure cluster)

If curl -k won't work then you need to copy and add certs from on prem to azure cluster.

Links which should help you do that

- https://docs.docker.com/ee/enable-client-certificate-authentication/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate

And found some informations about doing that with docker daemon

- https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

I hope it will help you. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having the same problem described here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43924.

[This solution](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43924#issuecomment-342636735) should probably work for you:

> As far as I remember this was a docker issue, not a kubernetes one.
> Docker does not use linux's ca certs. Nobody knows why.
>
> You have to install those certs manually (on every node that could
> spawn those pods) so that docker can use them:
>
> /etc/docker/certs.d/mydomain.com:1234/ca.crt
>
> This is a highly annoying issue as you have to butcher your nodes
> after bootstrapping to get those certs in there. And kubernetes spawns
> nodes all the time. How this issue has not been solved yet is a
> mystery to me. It's a complete showstopper IMO.

Then it's just a question of how to run this for every node. You could do that with a DaemonSet which runs a script from a ConfigMap, as described here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/automatically-bootstrapping-gke-nodes-with-daemonsets. That article refers to a GitHub project https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-gke-init-daemonsets-tutorial.
The magic is in the DaemonSet.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: node-initializer
  labels:
    app: default-init
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: default-init
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: node-initializer
        app: default-init
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: root-mount
        hostPath:
          path: /
      - name: entrypoint
        configMap:
          name: entrypoint
          defaultMode: 0744
      initContainers:
      - image: ubuntu:18.04
        name: node-initializer
        command: ["/scripts/entrypoint.sh"]
        env:
        - name: ROOT_MOUNT_DIR
          value: /root
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: root-mount
          mountPath: /root
        - name: entrypoint
          mountPath: /scripts
      containers:
      - image: "gcr.io/google-containers/pause:2.0"
        name: pause
```

You could modify the script that is in the ConfigMap to pull your cert and put it in the correct directory.